# SVG - polygon hover does not work correclty

Tags: css, svg, hover, polygon, mouse-cursor

As you can see on gif below, `:hover` state does not work properly when I move the mouse cursor from bottom polygon to upper polygon:

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />
  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,270" />
</svg>
```

**[[jsfiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/36Lcyvyw/)**

[image]

Tested in Chrome and Firefox - the result is the same.

How can I achieve SVG polygon turn `:hover` state on right after mouse cursor enters its borders?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere earlier that `fill: none` affects pointer events and that it was better to use `fill: transparent.` Try and see if that helps. It seems to work for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/36Lcyvyw/1/) but I can't post that as answer as I don't have a solid explanation.

Comment: Don't use fill: transparent, use pointer-events: visible

Comment: @Harry wow, I have no idea why but your suggestion works like a charm! If you can pop it into an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @limonte: Paulie has already added that, so I will not repeat it :) By the way, have a look at Robert's suggestion (he knows a lot more about SVG than me :))

Comment: thanks @RobertLongson I'll take a look at your suggestion!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no `fill` to catch the pointer event so it fails.

A simple transparent fill corrects it.

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: transparent;
}
polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />

  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,270" />
</svg>
```

***As mentioned by Robert Longson***

`pointer-events: visible` is the **preferred** and **performant** solution.

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: visible;
}
polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />

  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,270" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't use fill: transparent, use pointer-events: visible

Comment: @RobertLongson since it works like expected in my case, I think this is the right answer on my question.

Comment: @limonte It's **an** answer but it's not the **best** answer because it's non-standard and has worse performance characteristics than pointer-events

Comment: @RobertLongson it seems you're right. I got the expected behaviour with adding `pointer-events: visible;` Thank you once again for explanation.