# Animate each point of a polygon individually

Tags: animation, svg, polygon, snap.svg

I have a website-menu, which consists of multiple polygons, which the user can click on. Furthermore, the polygons share some of the nodes. So far so good (see the code below).

Now, I would like to animate these polygons in a way such that they dynamically change their shape in a slow and endless loop. To this end I need to animate each node individually. I thought of letting the nodes move along a path (e.g. a small circle), each one at its individual speed.

Is there a way to do this by using SVG/CSS only? Or do I need to look for a solution with js or snap? Since the menu is a core-functional part of the webpage, I want to keep it as simple and vanilla as possible.

Here's a working example with two polygons, which I copied from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137604/svg-polygon-hover-does-not-work-correclty).

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: transparent;
}
polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />

  <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,270" />
</svg>
```

The following snippet shows the only way I could come up with so far to move one single node. Unfortunately, it requires the coordinates of all the other points. Since the nodes are shared between the various polygons this solution does not work for me.

```
<polygon points="" fill="red">
 <animate attributeName="points" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
          from="0,0, 0,100, 100,100"
          to="0,0, 0,100, 100,50"/>
</polygon>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: maybe create the whole thing with a path so there's no duplication then animate the path's commands using SMIL.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson. I fear, that the areas won't be clickable if I use a path. Or do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: you'd have to work out what a click meant yourself, yes.

Comment: alternatively carefully construct the SMIL for each polygon so it's consistent with all the other polygon's motions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use javascript for this and I would use an array of points. Then I would animate the position of those points. You draw the polygons using those points. See function `function resetPoints()` in my code. I hope this is what you are asking for.

```js
let points = [
  {x:445,y:161,a:.7},
  {x:345,y:147,a:2.1},
  {x:500,y:10,a:3.9},
  {x:500,y:270,a:5.2}
]

let r = 20;// the radius of rotation. In this case is a unique value. It may be a different value for every point
let speed = .01;//the speed of rotation. In this case is a unique value. It may be a different value for every point 


//get center rotation
points.forEach(p=>{
  p.c = {};
  let a = 2*Math.PI - p.a;//angle
  p.c.x = p.x + r*Math.cos(a);
  p.c.y = p.y + r*Math.sin(a);
});



//resetPoints();

function Frame(){
  requestAnimationFrame(Frame)
  points.forEach(p=>{
    p.a += speed;
    p.x = p.c.x + r*Math.cos(p.a);
    p.y = p.c.y + r*Math.sin(p.a);
  });
  
  resetPoints();
}

Frame();

// a function to draw the polygons in base of the points

function resetPoints(){
  let pts1 = `${points[0].x}, ${points[0].y} 
            ${points[1].x}, ${points[1].y} 
            ${points[2].x}, ${points[2].y}`
  let pts2 = `${points[0].x}, ${points[0].y} 
            ${points[1].x}, ${points[1].y} 
            ${points[3].x}, ${points[3].y}`

a.setAttributeNS(null,"points",pts1);
b.setAttributeNS(null,"points",pts2);
}
```

```css
polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: transparent;
}
polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
  <polygon id="a" points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />

  <polygon id="b" points="445,161 345,174 500,270" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this is exactly, what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: There is a small typo: in function Frame() it should be sin(p.a) instead of cos(p.a). I tried to edit, but it needs a review first to be displayed.
(however, I think it looks even nicer, when the nodes are moving along axes instead of circles ;.))